# Issues Posting XML API Request in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, character-encoding

I would like to leverage python to post to an xml api and having a few issues from input params formatting. What is the best way of passing this in a python string like:

```
  body = '''<Employee>
                    <EmployeeId ID= {}/>
                </Employee>
                <Time>{}</Time>
                <Date>{}</Date>
    '''.format('ABCD','10:00','10/02/2019')
```

This works from a UI:

```
       <Employee>
            <EmployeeId ID= ABCD/>
       </Employee>
       <Time>10:00</Time>
       <Date>10/02/2019</Date>
```

I tried .strip() and .replace() to get rid of the string but not much progress. What would be the best approach ? encoding ? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an issue, where's the problem?

Comment: XML shall have a single root element, otherwise it is a not well-formed XML